# How to Convert Json Array To PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

these are my two functions used in model for save & retrieve the  data in my database

Here is my function for save data //

```
  public function save_po($supid,$cart,$total)
  {
    $num=rand(1,99999);
    $date=Date('Y-m-d');
    $array_string=json_encode($cart);// $cart is an multi dimensional array here
    $data = array(
   'num' => $num ,
   'date' => $date ,
   'supplier' => $supid,
   'status' => 'RAISED',
   'items'=>$array_string,
   'terms'=>'Purchase Order Valid For 15days From the day Of Creation',
   'user'=>'1',
   'total'=>$total);

         $result=$this->db->insert('purchase_order',$data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        {
        return TRUE;    
        }
        else
        {
        return FALSE;   
        }   

  }
```

**here is my code for retrieve the data**

```
    public function get_previous($brand,$model,$sup_id) {


                     $this->db->where('supplier',$sup_id);    
            $result= $this->db->get(' purchase_order');
            if($result->num_rows()>0)
            {
                $result_array=array();
                foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
                {
                $result_array[]=$row['items'];
                }

                return $result_array;
            }
            else
            return FALSE;

        }
```

now i'm calling that retrieve function in my controller like this.

```
 $data['previous']=$this->purchases_model->get_previous($x,$y,$z);
 $arr=(array)($data['previous']);
 print_r($arr);// it was giving the below output of array which is in json format.
 $php_array=json_decode($arr); // here it was displaying error like json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given .
```

Can you please help me to get that data in PHP array format.

```
(
    [0] => {"526728b1bdca73ca2919bb92e0dbe197":{"rowid":"526728b1bdca73ca2919bb92e0dbe197","id":"6","qty":"4","price":"25","name":"PARACETMOL","tax":5,"options":{"Brand":"RANBAXY","Category":"MEDICINES","Taxes":"ADDITIONAL(5%)=>5|","FT":5},"subtotal":100}}
    [1] => {"d28401e301187f7934510c203ffa90e2":{"rowid":"d28401e301187f7934510c203ffa90e2","id":"1","qty":"4","price":"15000","name":"CANVAS2","tax":3000,"options":{"Brand":"MICROMAX","Category":"ANDROID MOBILES","Taxes":"ADDITIONAL(5%)=>3000|","FT":3000},"subtotal":60000}}
    [2] => {"769f5f6be645e88fcb574d5e2ada318a":{"rowid":"769f5f6be645e88fcb574d5e2ada318a","id":"3","qty":"4","price":"19000","name":"JUNGLE","tax":9120,"options":{"Brand":"MICROMAX","Category":"FEATURED MOBILES","Taxes":"VAT(12%)=>9120|","FT":9120},"subtotal":76000}}
    [3] => {"8875353ac430b7302eb1bef0660205b3":{"rowid":"8875353ac430b7302eb1bef0660205b3","id":"6","qty":"4","price":"25","name":"PARACETMOL","tax":12,"options":{"Brand":"RANBAXY","Category":"MEDICINES","Taxes":"VAT(12%)=>12|","FT":12},"subtotal":100}}
)
```

i want to convert this array into php array

Comment: you can use `json_decode` function

Comment: There is no character limitation for questions, you are encouraged to use proper English words, such as "you" instead of "u" and "please" instead "plz". This will also make use take you more serious.

Answer (score 3):

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I think the error message is pretty clear: You are passing an array to `json_decode`, but it expects a string. It looks like you have to iterate over array:

```
foreach($arr as $i => $json) {
    $arr[$i] = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` is an `array`

so you can use iterate the array and the use `json_decode`[More Details on Json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode)

```
foreach($array as $key => $Value) {
    $arr[$key] = json_decode($Value, true); // this will give key val pair array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and get save the result in another variable.

**Function:**

```
function objectToArray( $object ) {
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) ) {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) ) {
        $object = (array) $object;
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$variable = objectToArray(json_decode($arr));
print_r($variable);
```